# error while running python script using AutoSys

Tags: python, autosys, jil

I am running a python script using AutoSys but it is giving error.
The problem lies in the version of python, Instead of calling python 3.8 auto sys is calling python 2.7
How can I change the path of python in autosys?

Comment: I am running my code in ec2.

Comment: Assuming it's a Linux EC2 instance, log into that host and verify which python version is available/ installed ?

Comment: Also, check by updating Autosys job command attribute as "python3 /absolute_path/script.py"

Comment: @Piyush thanks a lot it worked by giving full path of python3

Comment: glad to know it was of some help. In that case, could you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

Step1: Check the python version on the host. Below would confirm the path of the respective python binary.

```
bash-3.2$ which python
/usr/bin/python
bash-3.2$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
```

Step2: Check Autosys job attribute to use python for 2.x and python3 for 3.x

```
update_job: YourAutosysJobName
command: python3 /absolute_path/python_script.py
```

Happy to help !!